# How to match two patterns in one pointcut expression

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I want to define my pointcut to match two kinds of methods:

1. all methods from class `org.mypackage.Foo` with names starting with "update"
2. all methods from the same class with names starting with "delete"

I tried the following:

```
@Before("execution (* org.mypackage.Foo.update*(..) ) && execution(* org.mypackage.Foo.delete*(..) )")
public void verify()
{
  //verify if user has permission to modify...
}
```

It doesn't work. When I call either a Foo.update*() method or a Foo.delete*() method, verify() is not invoked.

How should I change it?

Comment: Instead of an and `&&` use or `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 option to match patterns in pointcut expression. The pointcut expression may be either a simple reference to a named pointcut, or a pointcut expression declared in place.

1. By creating individual method for respective point cut. And using that method name as reference in @Before advice.

```java
    @Pointcut("execution(* org.mypackage.Foo.update*(..))")
    private void fooUpdate() {}
    
    @Pointcut("execution(* org.mypackage.Foo.delete*(..))")
    private void fooDelete() {}
    
    @Before("fooUpdate() || fooDelete()")
    public void verify() {
      // verify if user has permission to modify...
    }
```

2. Directly declaring pointcut expression in place.

```java
    @Before("execution(* org.mypackage.Foo.update*(..)) || execution(* org.mypackage.Foo.delete*(..))")
    public void verify() {
      // verify if user has permission to modify...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `&&` to `||` in your expression.